# Awk and calculating start time from end time and duration

Tags: time, awk

I have a file with date, end time and duration in decimal format and I need to calculate the start time. The file looks like:

```
20140101;1212;1.5
20140102;1515;1.58
20140103;1759;.69
20140104;1100;12.5
...
```

The duration 1.5 for the time 12:12 means one and a half hours and the start time would be 12:12 - 1:30 = 10:42 AM or 11:00 - 12.5 = 11:00 - 12:30 = 22:30 PM. Is there an easy way for calculating such time differences in Awk or is it the good ol' split-multiply-subtract-and-handle-the-day-break-yourself all over again?

Since the values are in hours and minutes, only the minutes matter and the seconds can be discarded, for example duration 1.58 means 1:34 and the leftover 0.8 seconds can be discarded.

I'm on GNU Awk 4.1.3

Comment: and what does `1.58` mean? 1h 34min and some seconds? Better show also what is the expected output.

Comment: is your version of awk actually gawk? check with `awk --version`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `gawk` take adventage of its native `time functions`:

```
gawk -F\; '{tmst=sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s 00",\
                  substr($1,1,4),\
                  substr($1,5,2),\
                  substr($1,7,2),\
                  substr($2,1,2),\
                  substr($2,3,2))
            t1=mktime(tmst)
            seconds=sprintf("%f",$3)+0
            seconds*=60*60
            difference=strftime("%H%M",t1-seconds)
            print $0""FS""difference}' file
```

**Results**:

```
20140101;1212;1.5;1042
20140102;1515;1.58;1340
20140103;1759;.69;1717
20140104;1100;12.5;2230
```

Check: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html

**Explanation:**

- `tmst=sprintf(..)` :used to  create a date string from the file
  that conforms with the `datespec` of `mktime` function `YYYY MM
  DD HH MM SS [DST]`.
- `t1=mktime(tmst)` :turn datespec into a timestamp than **can be
  handle** by `gawk` (as the number of seconds elapsed since 1
  January 1970)
- `seconds=sprintf("%f",$3)+0` : convert third field to float.
- `seconds*=60*60` : convert hours (in float) to seconds.
- `difference=strftime("%H%M",t1-seconds)` : get the difference in
  *human* maner, hours an minutes.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I actually tried playing around with mktime but got negative values on the fourth row. I must've made some mistake.

Comment: Most likely a *strange* character issue..try to enter the whole row manually in the file

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend to use a programming language which supports datetime calculations, because the calculation can be tricky in detail because daylight saving shifts. You can use Python for example:

*start_times.py*:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

with open('input.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:

        end_day = row[0]
        end_time = row[1]
        # Create a datetime object
        end = datetime.strptime(end_day + end_time, "%Y%m%d%H%M")

        # Translate duration into minutes
        duration=float(row[2])*60

        # Calculate start time
        start = end - timedelta(minutes=duration)

        # Column 3 is the start day (can differ from end day!)
        row.append(start.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
        # Column 4 is the start time
        row.append(start.strftime("%H%M"))

        print ';'.join(row)
```

Run:

```
python start_times.py
```

Output:

```
20140101;1212;1.5;20140101;1042
20140102;1515;1.58;20140102;1340
20140103;1759;.69;20140103;1717
20140104;1100;12.5;20140103;2230  <-- you see, the day matters!
```

The above example is using the system's timezone. If the input data refers to a different timezone, Pyhon's datetime module allows to specify it.

Comment: Very nice Python snippet! Probably better to move `import pdb` to the beginning, not to import it every time you loop.

Comment: @fedorqui It was just for debugging! :) Thanks. `pdb.set_trace()` is really nice!

Comment: Wow, I had never heard about this module, really good to know about it : )

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
     { h=substr($2,0,2); m=substr($2,3,2); mins=h*60 + m; diff=mins - $3*60;
       print $0, int(diff/60) ":" int(diff%60)
     }' file
```

That is, convert everything to minutes and then back to hours/minutes.

#### Test

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{h=substr($2,0,2); m=substr($2,3,2); mins=h*60 + m; diff=mins - $3*60; print $0, int(diff/60) ":" int(diff%60)}' a
20140101;1212;1.5;10:42
20140102;1515;1.58;13:40
20140103;1759;.69;17:17
```

Comment: It can't handle for example "20140104;1100;12.5". It produces "20140101;1100;12.5;-1:-30".

Comment: @JamesBrown then provide a more representative input from the beginning, together with the expected output.

Comment: @JamesBrown what should be the output for the example you provided? Update your original question with such info